# Track changes in time series data table in R

Tags: r, performance, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a `data.table` like this

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 2)),
  time = c(seq(1, 3, 1), seq(1, 4, 1), seq(3, 4)),
  value1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  value2 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
)
```

which print like this

```
    id   time   value1 value2
1:  1    1      0      0
2:  1    2      0      1
3:  1    3      0      0
4:  2    1      0      1
5:  2    2      2      0
6:  2    3      0      0
7:  2    4      0      0
8:  3    3      0      0
9:  3    4      1      1
```

Now I want to create two new columns tracking when there last was a non-zero value in the value columns for each `id`. Ie. I want a resulting data table as follows

```
    id   time   value1  last_change1  value2  last_change2
1:  1    1      0       NA            0       NA
2:  1    2      0       NA            1       0
3:  1    3      0       NA            0       1
4:  2    1      0       NA            1       0
5:  2    2      2       0             0       1
6:  2    3      0       1             0       2
7:  2    4      0       2             0       3
8:  3    3      0       NA            0       NA
9:  3    4      1       0             1       0
```

Does anybody have a good solution for this that performs good as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `zoo::na.locf` to fill row-number(group specific) of the last `non-zero` values in place holder for `0` in corresponding rows in `value` columns. Finally, subtract the `row-number` of last `non-zero` from the current row number (group-wise e.g. `.I-.I[1]+1`).

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

df[, c("last_change1", "last_change2") := 
     lapply(.SD, function(x){as.integer((.I-.I[1]+1) - na.locf(as.integer(ifelse(x == 0, NA_integer_, .I-.I[1]+1)), na.rm = FALSE))}),
   .SDcols = value1:value2, by=id]
```

Edited: Added simplified version based on suggestion from `@DavidArenburg`

```
df[, c("last_change1", "last_change2") := 
   lapply(.SD, function(x){.I - na.locf(ifelse(x == 0, NA_integer_, .I), na.rm = FALSE)}),
   .SDcols = value1:value2, by=id]


#Modified df
df
#    id time value1 value2 last_change1 last_change2
# 1:  1    1      0      0           NA           NA
# 2:  1    2      0      1           NA            0
# 3:  1    3      0      0           NA            1
# 4:  2    1      0      1           NA            0
# 5:  2    2      2      0            0            1
# 6:  2    3      0      0            1            2
# 7:  2    4      0      0            2            3
# 8:  3    3      0      0           NA           NA
# 9:  3    4      1      1            0            0
```

Comment: Nicely done. I think you could simplify to just `function(x) .I - na.locf(ifelse(x == 0, NA_integer_, .I), na.rm = FALSE)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Absolutely fantastic. I had overlooked the fact the `.I[1]` was getting nullified at the end. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution: this now works with as many non-zero values as you can find. Thanks to @DavidArenburg for pointing out. I have to say that the example should have considered that case.

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
    split(x,cumsum(x)) %>% lapply(function(x) {
    if(any(x!=0)){ IND2<-(min(which(x!=0)):length(x));x<-NA;x[IND2]<-0:(length(IND2)-1);return(as.numeric(x))} else {x[]<-NA;return(as.numeric(x))}
    }) %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
}


df[,`:=`(last_change1 = fun1(value1), last_change2 = fun1(value2)),by="id"]
```

result:

```
   id time value1 value2 last_change1 last_change2
1:  1    1      0      0           NA           NA
2:  1    2      0      1           NA            0
3:  1    3      0      0           NA            1
4:  2    1      0      1           NA            0
5:  2    2      2      0            0            1
6:  2    3      0      0            1            2
7:  2    4      0      0            2            3
8:  3    3      0      0           NA           NA
9:  3    4      1      1            0            0
```

Comment: This won't work if there are more than one non-zero values in a certain group

Comment: Can you give an example? Ill have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Set `id = 1` for the whole data set and see what you get